# C, Fixed width characters

Tags: c, binary, char

I am reading/writing `char`s to a binary file. The program doing the reading/writing may run on either a 32 or 64 bit machine. Furthermore, the file could be written in a 32-bit environment then read in 64 and vice-versa.

Therefore I need some way of storing `char`s that guarantees a certain width (the smaller the better). I'm sure there is an accepted/common way to do this, but being a C novice I don't know it, and also can't find anything via google..

Does any one know the trick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On any "normal" modern architecture `char`s are always of 8 bits, regardless of 64/32 bit issues. Those arise when you dump directly on a file the binary representation of `int` or other types (which can vary in size and byte ordering depending on architecture), but plain `char`s should be safe.

... obviously if you are writing text you should choose some encoding, but that's a completely different story...

Comment: I'm just writing urls actually, which will only be read by the program that generated the data, or a copy of it on another machine. (Its also not a big production thing) so I thought it would be acceptable to forgo any encoding. Is this an acceptable circumstance, or should I always encode?

Comment: As long as you know that on both end the default encoding used by the C library is the same you should be ok... Also, URLs are not as problematic as "generic" text, since troublesome characters should already be escaped.